# Como fazer várias Thread em um Loop em Java

Tags: java, json, http, multithreading

### Descrição do Problema

Eu estou fazendo uma Pokedex, em que uma da suas funcionalidades é filtrar todos os pokemons de um determinado tipo.

Eu consegui implementar essa funcionalidade, porém o tempo de execução não está bom... Demora cerca de 25 segundos para passar por todos os elementos, criar objetos pokemons e adicioná-los a um Vector.

Eu estou tentando resolver este problema com o uso de Threads. Invés de criar cada pokemon sequencialmente e adicionar no vector, eu estou tentando criar um laço de repetição que passo a posição de um JSONObject, onde se encontra o pokemon. E após todas as Threads serem concluídas irei colocar o 'Objeto Pokemon' resultante em um Vector...

A minha dúvida é:

1. Como passo essa posição do JSONObject;
2. Como salvo os resultados das Threads em um Vector, uma vez que todos usam um espaço na memória compartilhado;

### Código que pensei

```
    package model;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Vector;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    public class Pokemon_Tipo extends RequestClass implements Runnable
    {
        private Vector<Pokemon> SameType_Pokemons = new Vector<Pokemon>();
        private JSONArray root_types;

        public Pokemon_Tipo() {}

        // Este método é chamado com o tipo de pokemon desejado
        public Vector<Pokemon> Pokemon_type(String tipo)
        {
            try
            {
                // Nesta url está os link para os pokemons do determinado tipo
                String data = get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/"+tipo);

                // Método responsável para retornar um JSONObject com as
                // informações contidadas na String data
                JSONObject root = parse(data);

                // Lista de url para todos os pokemons
                this.root_types = root.getJSONArray("pokemon");

                // loop para entrar em todos url e criar os pokemons
                for(int i=0; i<root_types.length(); i++)
                {
                    new Thread(this).start();
                }

                // Após todas as threads finalizar, retornar esse
                // vector
                // Dúvida como esperar todas as threads terminarem?
                return SameType_Pokemons;
            }

            catch (IllegalStateException | IOException | JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        //  Thread
        public void run()
        {
            // Pelo a URL uma posição de um JSONArray
            // Dúvida, como passo essa posição i ?
            JSONObject url = root_types.getJSONObject(i)
                    .getJSONObject("pokemon");

            // Após a Thread finalizar, salvar o resultado no Vector
            // Dúvida como salvar em um espaço compartilhado?
            SameType_Pokemons.addElement(new Pokemon(url));
        }


    }
```

Eu pensei em solucionar esse problema com Threads, caso alguém tenha uma solução mais inteligente, estou aberto a sugestões ;)

Comment: Paralização sozinha talvez não seja a melhor solução para o seu problema. Processar as URLS em paralelo irá sim ajudar na velocidade de carregamento, porém, em determinado momento você irá saturar o limite de conexões e seu aplicativo basicamente terá várias threads bloqueadas em IO. Algumas ideias: 1. Faça download dos dados e grave localmente; 2. Se a idéia é fazer com que a Pokédex seja atualizada automaticamente com novos Pokémons você pode fazer esse processo de atualização no *background*; 3. Não carregue todos os Pokémons de uma vez. Abra em demanda ou implemente uma lógica de paginação